# Play gif's in lua?

Tags: iphone, ios, lua, gif

How can i display `animated gif's` in lua?I searched a lot on the web but didn't found nothing.I'm using director and tried this code,

```
   local backgroundImage = display.newGifRect( "mainmenu.gif", 480, 320 )
   backgroundImage.x = 240; backgroundImage.y = 160
   menuGroup:insert( backgroundImage )
```

I thought it should be done as an image but it doesn't worked.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm using Corona SDK and lua language.

Comment: @lhf - great comment.  Really helps the OP and drives the conversation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIImageView do not support animated gif by default

you will need to use UIWebView or [glgif](https://github.com/jamesu/glgif)

---

EDIT: (ABOVE APPLIES TO UIKIT ONLY)

My guess would be you need to use `movieclip.newAnim( )` / sprite sheet

```
local myAnim = movieclip.newAnim({ "img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png", "img4.png" })
myAnim:play()
```

for sprite, you can use tools like [Avi4Bmp](http://www.bottomap.com/Software/A4B/A4B.html) to convert the animated gif, and take a look on the [doc](http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/sprite-sheets) (sample code included)

Comment: I wont down-vote you answer because i might bad explained my problem,i using corona SDK and lua to develop a game,so i'm not using and UI from Xcode!Just lua programming!

Comment: Can you provide the full code,i've just began developing in lua?Thanks for the answer!